# Probability of 10 (somewhat) consecutive events

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

My question to you: can you please tell me if I am doing things correctly or I am off base? Thanks!

Objective: to determine the probability of 10 independent people having a one base pair mutation (event) and all of these mutations have to occur within a 30 base pair span. Each event can be spaced a maximum of 3 base pairs from each other. The overall area for an event to occur (in this case) is 600 base pairs.

Assumptions: 
   -equal chance at a mutation
   -people are picked at random

Step A:
I used the addition rule to determine the probability of a single permutation. I choose 6 to allow for the maximum of 3 base pairs on each side of the variants and 600 to account for the overall area.

X = 600/600 * (6/600)^9

Step B: 
I accounted for the possible permutations in step 1 by accounting for the different combinations of the 10 independent events.

Answer: Y = 10! * X

Is my correct answer Y? 
Also, would this approach still work if I started using a group of say 1000 people? Or would I need to account for them in the equation as well?

*this is not a homework question. I am trying to answer a research question with this solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but your steps A and B seem completely unrelated to the question you asked before... could you clarify that?

Comment: You are aware that $600/600$ is just $1$ right? So why do you write $X=600/600*(6/600)^9$ instead of just $X=(6/600)^9$?